# Does immutablejs allow searching with a reference type

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have a piece of code that looks like this

```
const { Map } = require('immutable@4.0.0')

let map = new Map().setIn(["user",["alex","country"]],"Poland")
map.getIn(["user",["alex","country"])
```

I hope the above would return `"Poland"`, but such is not the case. I presume
the reference type `["alex", "country"]` is serialized differently when setting and querying. Any assistance on how to achieve this would be helpful. I shy away from having to handle the Array serialization manually

Comment: Is this your actual code? `map.getIn(["user",["alex","country"])` contains a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array isn't serialized. `immutable` uses the actual object (its reference) as a key and the equal operator to compare keys. That means that the first `["alex","country"]` and the second `["alex","country"]` are two different keys.

This snippet shows the problem:

```js
if (['alex', 'country'] !== ['alex', 'country']) {
  console.log('The references are different');
}
```

I have 3 solutions:

**1.  Store a reference in a variable**

You can store a reference to the array in a variable to use it as a key:

```
const { Map } = require('immutable');

const arr = ['alex', 'country'];
let map = new Map().setIn(['user', arr], 'Poland');
console.log(map.getIn(['user', arr]));
```

**2.  Serialize the array using `toString`**

An alternative solution is to serialize the arrays using `toString`:

```
const { Map } = require('immutable@4.0.0')

let map = new Map().setIn(["user",["alex","country"].toString()],"Poland")
map.getIn(["user",["alex","country"].toString()])
```

Example snippet:

```js
if (['alex', 'country'].toString() === ['alex', 'country'].toString()) {
  console.log('The serialized arrays are equal');
}
```

But remember that serializing different arrays can yield the same string:

```js
if (['alex', 'country'].toString() === ['alex,country'].toString()) {
  console.log('Serializing different arrays can yield the same string');
}
```

**3.  Flatten the array**

Another approach is to flatten the path array:

```
const { Map } = require('immutable');

let map = new Map().setIn(['user', ['alex', 'country']].flat(), 'Poland');
console.log(map.getIn(['user', ['alex', 'country']].flat()));
```

Comment: That would work if the const arr = ['alex', 'country'] was always composed and reference within the same context

Comment: @Ndifreke In that case you can't use non-primitives as key. `immutable` doesn't serialize objects.

Comment: flattening the Array is exactly what I needed, thanks

Comment: 4. Make the key a primitive, which can be reproduced at any time: `['alex','country'].join()`

Comment: @dube What's the difference between 4. `['alex','country'].join()` and 2. `["alex","country"].toString()`?

Comment: @jabaa nothing! (besides the formatting of the string) I misinterpreted the brackets of #2